# Text replacement using csv data

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array, split

I have 2 arguments, the first is a text file, and a second is a csv file.

The first file look like:

```
(name) from (address) is (age) years old.
```

The second file look like:

```
Name,Address,Age

James,London,34

Alex,New York,25
```

I want to replace this: (name) to James, (address) to (London) and (age) to 34 etc...

I want to output this: `James from London is 34 years old.` etc...

So how can I store the datas of csv file in a multidimensional array?
Like this $data[line number][column number]
For example the $data[1][0] should be: Alex

My code:

```
$parameter = $args[0]
$data = $args[1]

for($i = 1; $i -lt $data.lenght/3; $i++)
{
    $parameter.replace('(name)', '???') | Set-Content $parameter
    $parameter.replace('(address)', '???') | Set-Content $parameter
    $parameter.replace('(age)', '???') | Set-Content $parameter
    #I want to output $parameter

}
```

Comment: If you use `$data = Import-CSV "pathtocsvfile.csv"` you will have for example `Alex` in `$data[1].Name`, or `London` in `$data[0].Address`, would that work for you ?

Comment: And how can I output $parameter?
Write-Host doesn't work

Comment: I think you have to use `return`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Import-Csv

Example

```
$data = "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\test.csv"

$list = Import-Csv $data

$list
$list[0].Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your current input files, where `$template` is your string to have replacements done and `$path` is your source CSV, we could do something like this.

```
$template = Get-Content D:\temp\template.txt
$path = "d:\temp\test.csv"

$keys = ($template | Select-String "\(.*?\)" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
ForEach($csvEntry in (Import-CSV $path)){
    $result = $template
    $keys | ForEach-Object{
        $result = $result.Replace($_,$csvEntry."$($_.Trim("()"))")
    } 
    $result
}
```

Get the `$keys` that are values to be replaced that hopefully have matching values in the CSV file. In this case `$keys` is `@("(name)","(address)","(age)")`. Then we go through each row in the CSV and for each row we do a replacement for each key that we have located. Then simply passing the `$result` as output.

```
James from London is 34 years old.
Alex from New York is 25 years old.
```

---

If you have control over your template file this could be *a lot easier* if it looked like this: "{0} from {1} is {2} years old.". That way you can just use the [format operator](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) and positionally assign the CSV values.

```
Import-CSV $path | ForEach-Object{$template -f $_.Name, $_.Address, $_.Age}
```

Same results with less code.